# How to read memory layout of an array of base class pointers pointing to derived class

Tags: c++

I did some experiments in order to understand how the memory layout looks like for an array of base class pointers.

**Question**> After the initialization(Case I & II), why the distance between each pointer is `20` bytes. Where does this number come from?

Thank you

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:  
  virtual void PrintMe() const {
    cout << "class A; ";
  }

  ~A() {}
};

class B : public A {
private:
  int num;
public:

  virtual void PrintMe() const {
    cout << "class B; ";
  }
};

int main() {

  int a[2];  

  cout << "&a[0]: " << hex << &a[0] << endl;
  cout << "&a[1]: " << hex << &a[1] << endl;
  cout << "sizeof(int): " << sizeof(int) << endl;
  cout << "sizeof(int*): " << sizeof(int*) << endl;
  cout << "sizeof(A): " << sizeof(A) << endl;
  cout << "sizeof(A*): " << sizeof(A*) << endl;
  cout << "sizeof(B): " << sizeof(B) << endl;
  cout << "sizeof(B*): " << sizeof(B*) << endl;

  A* vec[5];
  cout << "Before initializatiion: " << endl;
  for(int i=0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
    cout << "vec[" << i << "]: " << hex << vec[i] << endl;
  }

  cout << "After initialization with A* ONLY: " << endl;  // case I
  for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
    vec[i] = new A();
  for(int i=0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
    vec[i]->PrintMe();
    cout << "vec[" << i << "]: " << hex << vec[i] << endl;
  }

  cout << "After initialization with B* & A*: " << endl; // case II
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      vec[i] = new B();
  for(int i=3; i < 5; i++)
    vec[i] = new A();

  for(int i=0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
    vec[i]->PrintMe();
    cout << "vec[" << i << "]: " << hex << vec[i] << endl;
  }  

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
&a[0]: 0x7fff0a6d3c40
&a[1]: 0x7fff0a6d3c44
sizeof(int): 4
sizeof(int*): 8
sizeof(A): 8
sizeof(A*): 8
sizeof(B): 10
sizeof(B*): 8
Before initializatiion: 
vec[0]: 0x2
vec[1]: 0x4011ed
vec[2]: 0x7f7b9a2a6a70
vec[3]: 0x401190
vec[4]: 0
After initialization with A* ONLY: 
class A; vec[0]: 0xc51010
class A; vec[1]: 0xc51030
class A; vec[2]: 0xc51050
class A; vec[3]: 0xc51070
class A; vec[4]: 0xc51090
After initialization with B* & A*: 
class B; vec[0]: 0xc510b0
class B; vec[1]: 0xc510d0
class B; vec[2]: 0xc510f0
class A; vec[3]: 0xc51110
class A; vec[4]: 0xc51130
```

Comment: Not 20 bytes - 0x20==32 bytes. That's probably the granularity of the memory allocator on your system. Note that the outcome doesn't in any way depend on the fact that pointers are stored in array elements - you are just making several memory allocations in a row, and printing addresses of memory blocks the allocator manufactures for you.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, good catch! I printed the results based on https://coderpad.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fill up an array of pointers using:

```
for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
    vec[i] = new A();
```

There is no guarantee that the difference between `vec[1]` and `vec[0]` has any relationship with `sizeof(A)`. It is pointless to give any significance to that.

If you use:

```
A aArray[5];
for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
    vec[i] = &(aArray[i]);
```

the difference between `vec[1]` and `vec[0]` is guaranteed to be `sizeof(A)`.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing 32 bytes between consecutive allocations.  There's nothing guaranteeing this will be a fixed (or even increasing) value, only that each allocation will be unique and non-overlapping (until you deallocate some of them, then it can be reused).

So it's not that the size of anything is 32 bytes, rather that's the alignment of your standard library's allocator.  Which is sensible, as a general-purpose allocate needs to align to the maximum possible required alignment on the platform.  32 bytes is the equivalent of a 256-bit AVX register.